# What is best practice for inheriting less files from a custom theme?

Tags: magento2

I have two themes (theme1, theme2). theme1 inherits from luma, theme2 inherits from theme1. What is best practice for theme2 to inherit theme1's custom less styles? Currently I am naming my custom less files _theme1.less and _them2.less and for theme2 to inherit _theme1.less, I've added @import '_theme1.less' to the _sources.less file for theme1 which overrides the luma _sources.less file, then theme2 then inherits the _sources.less file from theme1 which imports _theme1.less. This is a solution that works and is infinitely extensible but I feel like it's not exactly best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a _theme.less inside your theme 1 and it should be available to use in theme 2 as well since you've configured it as a parent.

_theme.less is a file that already exists in Luma for example.

Answer (score 1):

I've yet to find any stated best practice in this regard, although I'm typically hesitant to override more files than necessary except for **_extend.less** and then **_theme.less** which is already stated by Magento as recommended to be overridden for variable declaration.

My recommendation would be to add your additional extension file within your child theme's **_extend.less**.

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/
├── {theme1}
│   ├── web/
│   │   ├── css/
│   │   │   ├── extend.less (add `@import '_extend-2.less'; in this file)
│   │   │   ├── _extend-2.less (leave file blank as a placeholder)
├── {theme2}
│   ├── web/
│   │   ├── css/
│   │   │   ├── _extend-2.less (add your styles to override the parent)
```

It feels  a little cleaner to me than your method since we don't have to mess with **_sources.less**.  Although **_sources.less** doesn't seem like a major override so I don't see anything really wrong with your solution, but it is just one more file that needs to be checked during updates and then your included files will be added earlier than with the normal **_extend.less** method I suggested.

I would love to hear if someone has a better method, though.